# Jupyterhub: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'jupyterhub-proxy.pid'

Tags: python, linux, proxy, sudo, jupyterhub

I'm trying to install Jupyterhub on Linux server.
So I have sudo rights but I'm not a root.
I already configured JupyterHub and it's config, so I can run it in single-user mode (from different folders too).

But I have this error when trying to start multi-user as described here:
[official documentation link](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/wiki/Installation-of-Jupyterhub-on-remote-server#run-jupyterhub-as-a-system-service).

I faced the same problem before with `configurable-http-proxy` and `jupyterhub.sqlite` - the problem was multi-user script try to save this files in system directory (`/lib/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service` or  `/etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service`).

I changes such parameters in `jupyter_config.py`:

```
## url for the database. e.g. `sqlite:///jupyterhub.sqlite`
c.JupyterHub.db_url = 'sqlite:////data/jupyterhub/jupyterhub.sqlite'

## DEPRECATED since version 0.8. Use ConfigurableHTTPProxy.command
#c.JupyterHub.proxy_cmd = []
c.ConfigurableHTTPProxy.command = '/data/anaconda3/envs/fraud/bin/configurable-http-proxy'
```

So I tried the same way for `jupyterhub-proxy.pid`:

```
## File to write PID Useful for daemonizing JupyterHub.
c.JupyterHub.pid_file = '/data/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-proxy.pid'
```

But looks like JupyterHub ignores it and still trying to save it to system directory!
I add `print` to `jupyterhub/proxy.py` at `_write_pid_file(self)` function:

```
self.log.info("Writing log: %s", self.pid_file)
self.log.info("Writing log: %s", os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
```

Output:

> [I 2019-12-19 20:23:50.289 JupyterHub proxy:562] Writing proxy pid file: jupyterhub-proxy.pid
>
> [I 2019-12-19 20:23:50.290 JupyterHub proxy:564] Writing log: /

My idea - maybe there is another one config parameter I need to change, but I can't find anythig relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me setting the `c.ConfigurableHTTPProxy.pid_file` parameter in the jupyterhub configuration file.